# In Flutter how to make SingleChildScrollView scroll horizontally as well as vertically with fixed height

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I am creating an App that will have multiple tables on the same page. I want these tables to have a MaxHeight of say 200 and the table should be able to scroll both-ways, i,e. horizontally as well as vertically. I tried to nest SingleChildScrollView within another SingleChildScrollView which doesn't work. Here is code:

```
return Card(
  color: const Color.fromARGB(0, 183, 183, 202),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,          
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              widget.dataScreenTitle,
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
            DataTable(
              columns: columnTitles,
              rows: dataRows,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And there is no way to specify the height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you require is to use a **[`ConstrainedBox`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConstrainedBox/ConstrainedBox.html)** widget along with a single `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
return Card(
  color: const Color.fromARGB(0, 183, 183, 202),
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 200), // Set maxHeight here
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                widget.dataScreenTitle,
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              DataTable(
                columns: columnTitles,
                rows: dataRows,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

***[DARTPAD DEMO](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0b7b517960e1c9fa2ba3c66f25e6f56d)***